# Angular v5 service worker not working on server production where as working on http-server

Tags: angular5, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I have recently integrated service worker for my pwa issue I am facing is that when i run the http-server command within the dist server i can see the service worker within browser application tab with service worker registered. But same dist when i upload to my server and access the url I am not able to see the service worker as registered. Does any one has idea what may be the issue ??

Also how to register service worker over https SSL?

Comment: Service workers only work if you are using localhost (http and https) or via https for security purposes. You can find more information at the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413244/why-do-service-workers-only-work-over-https

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it over HTTPS domain and service worker will be loaded.
It works for me.

I use cloudflare to manage https requests because it's free.
i hope this helps you.

[Why am I seeing "Error - Only secure origins are allowed" for my service worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373166/why-am-i-seeing-error-only-secure-origins-are-allowed-for-my-service-worker?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

You can't register service worker with **http** except in **localhost**. I had the same issue in my application and used **https** URL to serve the application and working properly.

use **https** instead of **http**